react infinite image scroll animation
I am trying to create an infinite scroll animation for some images. The issue is that the images have a weird jump behaviour when the animation duration is completed. I implemented the same on text and it works without issues but not for the images.
CSS:
.outter-scroller{
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(
        90deg,
        transparent,
        white 20%,
        white 80%,
        transparent
      );
      mask: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, white 20%, white 80%, transparent);
    }
    .inner-scroller{
        width: max-content;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        animation: scroll 20s linear infinite;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        }

JSX:
import { useEffect } from "react"


const sourceImages = ['src/assets/ic1.jpg', 'src/assets/ic2.jpg', 'src/assets/ic3.jpg', 'src/assets/ic4.jpg', 'src/assets/ic4.jpg', 'src/assets/ic5.jpg', 'src/assets/ic6.jpg', 'src/assets/ic7.jpg', 'src/assets/ic8.jpg']

const ImageSectionAnimatedAuto = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const handleAnimation = () => {
            const scrollerInner = document.querySelector('.inner-scroller')
            const scrollerContent = Array.from(scrollerInner.children)
            scrollerContent.forEach((item) => {
                const duplicatedItem = item.cloneNode(true)
                scrollerInner.appendChild(duplicatedItem)
            })
        }
        handleAnimation()
    }, [])
    return (
        <section className="bg-[#1d283a] w-full h-[100vh] flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
            <h1 className="text-6xl text-white text-center">Infinite scroll</h1>
            <div className="outter-scroller md:w-[60vw] w-[600px] py-10">
                <ul className="inner-scroller flex gap-5">
                    {["HTML", "CSS", "JAVASCRIPT", "SSG", "WEBDEV", "ANIMATION", "UI/UX"].map((item) => (
                        <li className="m-0 text-white rounded-2xl px-6 py-2 bg-slate-500 shadow-lg" key={item}>{item}</li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
             <div className="outter-scroller py-5 flex w-[80vw] overflow-hidden">
                <div className="inner-scroller flex gap-5">
                    {sourceImages.map((image, _i) => (
                        <img key={_i} src={image} className="aspect-video w-[200px] rounded-xl" />
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    )
}

export default ImageSectionAnimatedAuto

I am just trying to recreate this: https://codepen.io/kevinpowell/pen/BavVLra

I wrapped the images inside a div and it worked.
<div className="test-images m-0 p-0 flex gap-5">
                    {sourceImages.map((image, _i) => (
                        <div key={_i} className="square">
                            <img src={image} className="m-0 p-0 flex rounded-xl" />
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>

